# I get the following error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /posts/post/edit Couldn't find Post with 'id'=post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building a blog and have implemented an edit post function but get the following error message: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /posts/post/edit
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=post I am using rails 5

Thank you in advance.

```
**Index.html.erb**
<div class="banner-container">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="banner-gradient-shadow"></div>
      <div class="banner-content banner-font">
        <h1>
          Some text
        </h1>
        <p>
          <strong>More text</strong>.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <% @posts.each do |p| %>
   <%= render "card", post: p %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Card partial**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url('post.photo_url');">
    <div class="card-category"><%= post.created_at.strftime("Posted %a %m %b %Y at %I:%M%p")  %></div>
      <div class="card-description">
        <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
        <p><%= post.summary %></p>
      </div>
      <!-- <img class="card-user avatar" src="user.jpg"> -->
      <%= link_to "", post_path(post), class: "card-link"%>
    </div>
     <% if current_user %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(:post), :class => "btn btn-    default" %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <h1>Editing post</h1>
   <%= simple_form_for :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :summary %>
    <%= f.input :post_content, as: :text %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-danger"%>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :edit]

 def index
 @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").all
 end

def show
@comment = Comment.new
end

def new
@post = Post.new
end

def edit

end

def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
 redirect_to post_path(@post)
 else
 render :show
end
end

def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to @post
  else
  render :show
  end
 end


def destroy
end

def set_post
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :post_content, :summary, photo: [], video: [])
end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
root to: 'posts#index'
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update] do
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post.id), :class => "btn btn-default" %>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `:post` to `post` in **card partial**

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

Rails is sending `:post` as value of `:id` like {'id' => ':post'}

And `set_params` is trying to find it with `params[:id]` which is ':post'

```
@post = Post.find(:post)
```

Comment: I did try that. for some reason it appears to go wrong at the controller when I remove the set_post action for edit the error goes and lets me get to the edit form but then when I add data to the form I get the sam error again.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes I did that to no avail.  Is the problem with the index.html.erb when I render the partial?

Comment: ahh.. yes you are passing `p` as locale and using `post` so you need to change `post` to `p` in your card partial wherever you have used it

Comment: and I believe you must be getting errors in  `post.title` as well

Comment: I have no issues with the title and changing post to p edit still has the same error. I think I will try moving the edit link into the show action and use the show params.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with the changes below:

**index.html.erb**
**no change**

**card partial**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url('post.photo_url');">
    <div class="card-category"><%= post.created_at.strftime("Posted %a %m %b %Y at %I:%M%p")  %></div>
      <div class="card-description">
        <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
        <p><%= post.summary %></p>
      </div>
      <%= link_to "", post_path(post), class: "card-link"%>
    </div>
     <% if current_user %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
   <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <h1>Editing post</h1>
       <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Enter a title" %>
        <%= f.input :summary, placeholder: "Short summary of post" %>
        <%= f.input :post_content, as: :text %>
        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-danger"%>
       <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```